# ¿Cómo conectar una aplicacion c++ con una base de datos SQL server?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, odbc

Estoy intentando conectar una aplicación realizada en c++ con una base de datos SQLSERVER, he encontrado que hay diferentes formar de realizar esto, en mi caso he optado por utilizar odbc, pero no he utilizado MFC para realizar dicha conexión. He decidido optar por una biblioteca llamada  libodbc++ http://libodbcxx.sourceforge.net/ . He seguido las indicaciones de la documentación de Microsoft para realizar odbc; he instalado el driver SQLserver odbc y he creado el DSN para la conexión con la base de datos.

Después de instalar la biblioteca mencionada, linkear a mi proyecto y compilar, decidí realizar la conexión con la base de datos, haciendo uso de las formas que  facilita la biblioteca, sin embargo para mi sorpresa y dolor, tras ejecutar la sentencia de conexión se dispara una excepción con el siguiente error:

> Failed to connect to datasource:[Microsoft][Administrador de controladores ODBC] Longitud de cadena o de buffer no valida.

Una búsqueda rápida en Google arroja a que esto es problema común en java, pero no se como lidiar con esto en c++. no se si la biblioteca escogida sea la mejor forma de conectarme, desconozco si las clases de MFC faciliten esta operación o si MFC es exclusivo para proyectos MFC de VC++.

Comment: [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Si no enseñas código en forma de ejemplo mínimo que reproduzca el error es imposible darte una respuesta